# Tensorflow: Convert output tensor to one-hot

Tags: tensorflow

What I want to do:  (from cs231n Winter course)
[image]

I'm gonna implement this using `tensorflow`.

But problem is I have no idea how to convert scores to one-hot (red colored line in above image)

Let say I have a `model` class which has all tensor operations as object variables.

`model.outputs` is an tensor operation(feedforward) to get the `scores` and I need to convert this `outputs` tensor to one-hot tensor **IN A DIFFERENCIABLE WAY** so that I can perform the gradient operation.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `scores` or `model.outputs` node has a shape of `[batch, #class]`. In the example below, we use `batch_size` = 2, and we have 4 `classes`.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch_size=2
num_classes=4
score = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.01], 
                     [0.8, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0]])

max_per_instance = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(score, axis=1), 0)
tiled = tf.tile(max_per_instance, [num_classes, 1])
n_hot = tf.cast(tf.equal(score, tf.transpose(tiled)), tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run(n_hot)

>> [[0 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: How tf.argmax is a differentiable operator?